# Spring Boot 2 Metrics Last invocation of @Timed Scheduled Job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

Gradle dependencies

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.0.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.0.1.RELEASE"
```

My scheduled task

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L * 57L)
@Timed("importCustomers")
open fun importCustomers() = importCustomerService.importCustomers()
```

When requesting the metrics for the job via actuator endpoint (http://xxx:yyy/actuator/metrics/importCustomers), I am able to see the number of invocations, max time and the total time.

Is there a way to see the timestamps the function has been invoked, or at least the latest time of invocation?

Like, last run at 2018-04-17T17:00:00.000Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built an example using Spring AOP to track scheduled jobs, source can be found at [Github](https://github.com/kevcodez/spring-boot-track-scheduled-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Not as of `micrometer:1.0.3` (the backing library for Spring Boot 2 metrics). The tracking-issue for this feature can be found [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/32).

Sharing your usecase and perhaps some hints on how or by which means you'd evaluate such a metric on the alarming/visualization side would help determine a good implementation. E.g. as proposed with an additional gauge metric.